# I can't find the pointer error that's causing an intermittent crash. Can you?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

This works most of the time, but I get an occasional crash.  There's a pointer problem somewhere but I can't see it yet.

The code takes words out of a string, and builds a linked list of them.  The words have to include adjacent punctuation, but no whitespace.  For example, the string:

> He said, 'blah blah!' and then died.

Would become the strings

> He
>
> said,
>
> 'blah
>
> blah!'
>
> and
>
> then
>
> died.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned longestword(char *str);

typedef struct _list{
    char *p;
    struct _list *next;
}list;


int main(void){
    char str[]="   'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs!'";
    unsigned k, i=0, l, j, wordscout;
    list *curr, *root=NULL;

    k =longestword(str);
    puts(str);
    printf("\nlongest word in string is %u letters long.", k);

    do{
        //  skip over any leading whitespace.
        for(; str[i] && isspace(str[i]); i++);
        if(!str[i]) break;

        //  count length of word that begins with str[i].
        for(wordscout=i, l=0; str[wordscout] && !isspace(str[wordscout]); wordscout++, l++);

        //  if this is first word, malloc space to root.
        if(root==NULL){
            if((root = malloc(sizeof(list))) == NULL){
                printf("\nmalloc() failed.");
                exit(1);
            }
            curr = root;
        }

        //  if not first word, malloc space to curr->next.
        else{
            if((curr->next = malloc(sizeof(list))) == NULL){
                printf("\nmalloc() failed.");
                exit(1);
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        //  malloc space in current struct for string.
        if((curr->p = malloc(1+l*sizeof(char))) == NULL){
            printf("\nmalloc() failed.");
            exit(1);
        }

        //  read first word into new space.
        j=0;
        while(!isspace(str[i])) curr->p[j++] = str[i++];
        curr->p[j] = '\0';

        //  check if word is there.
        printf("\n<<%s>>", curr->p);
    }while(str[wordscout]);
}


//  takes a null-terminated string, returns length of longest word in the string. word includes adjacent punctuation, but not whitespace.
unsigned longestword(char *str){

    //  check that word is null-terminated before carrying on.
    unsigned j,k,i,l;
    l = strlen(str);
    for(i=j=k=0; i<=l; i++){
        if(isalpha(str[i]) || ispunct(str[i])) j++;
        else if(j>k){ k=j; j=0; }
        else j=0;
    }
    return k;
}
```

The longestword() function can be ignored.  It works and it's for something else later on.

My output is the following, which is what I want.  But every now and again, it crashes after displaying this:

```
   'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think n
othing of tumbling down stairs!'

longest word in string is 8 letters long.
<<'Well!'>>
<<thought>>
<<Alice>>
<<to>>
<<herself,>>
<<'after>>
<<such>>
<<a>>
<<fall>>
<<as>>
<<this,>>
<<I>>
<<shall>>
<<think>>
<<nothing>>
<<of>>
<<tumbling>>
<<down>>
<<stairs!'>>
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.062 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking, you're not testing for '\0' in your copy loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(!isspace(str[i]))` will never terminate if the string doesn't end in whitespace.

The segfault might depend on how long it takes before whitespace turns up in the junk after the end of the string.

Instead you could do `while( i < wordscout )`. Note that `l` is redundant as you can and should use `wordscout - i`.

Comment: I just threw the `l` in there because when I did `wordscout-i` it wasn't given me the right numbers.  So I threw the `l` in there, so I could deal with that later. :)

Comment: Maybe you should investigate that issue as well then (e.g. `assert(l == wordscout - i);`). If that ever fails then something is seriously wrong

Comment: Changed it to "while(!isspace(str[i]) && str[i]) curr->p[j++] = str[i++];" and it seems fine now.

Comment: @KorganRivera Glad that it's working but I still would suggest using the same length expression in your `malloc` as you use in the loop to fill that space; otherwise the code will always be prone to buffer overflows and harder to visually check for correctness.

Comment: I think I am.  The `malloc` call for string space is different to the `malloc` call for struct space.  The first line with `wordscout` counts the word length, and the `malloc` call calls for that, plus space for the null terminator.

Comment: @KorganRivera the malloc length you give as `1+l*sizeof(char)` but then you use stuff involving `isspace` etc. to fill the loop. It's true that *currently* the code is not bugged because you compute `l` using the same `isspace` etc. condition, however it makes your code fragile because you have to maintain the same condition on two different lines and it would be easy to change one of them and introduce a buffer overflow.

Comment: Also you probably meant `(l+1)*sizeof(char)` although since `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, this won't actually lead to an issue

Answer (score 0):

You should set curr->next to NULL somewhere.

`curr->next = malloc()` is not enough because malloc() won't initialize `next` into NULL pointer. The **last** entry in your list will have `curr->next` pointing into a random place. Once you go to that place you program will crash.

If you do not understand the above here's how to demonstrate that:

**Add the following function into your  program:**

```
void foo()
{
    /* Fill the heap with garbage */
    list ** p = malloc(sizeof(list*)*8192);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8192;++i)
    {
       p[i]=malloc(sizeof(list));
       p[i]->next=p[i]; /*just something*/
    }
    for(i=0;i<8192;++i)
    {
       free( p[i] );
    }
    free(p);
}
```

**Run it BEFORE filling in the list:**

```
int main(void){
    foo(); <<-- my new line
    char str[]="......
```

**Print the LAST next pointer:**

```
    }while(str[wordscout]);

    printf("%p\n", curr->next); <<--my new line

    return 0;
```

Here's what it prints out:

```
...
<<tumbling>>
<<down>>
<<stairs!'>>0x1f61240 <<-- non-null here!
```

that means when you navigate your list you don't have proper END marker. Whoever is using your list won't know when they have reached the last element.

The best place to fix is is set curr->next after setting curr->p:

```
//  malloc space in current struct for string.
if((curr->p = malloc(1+l*sizeof(char))) == NULL){
    printf("\nmalloc() failed.");
    exit(1);
}

// At this moment curr->next should be NULL
curr->next=NULL;
```

Comment: Good find that he never terminates the linked list; however the posted code never traverses the list either (it outputs each word as it pushes the word into the list, then terminates)

Comment: It's the complete code.  And Matt's correct, it never traverses the list, but it will when I'm done.

Comment: @fukanchik I intend to null terminate my structs, but I'm not traversing the list yet.